# Unable to ping et1 - routing issue

Tags: networking, routing

I have an UBUNTU server VM installation with two NICs. eth0 is on the LAN network, configured by DHCP and is working fine. I manually configured eth1 with a static IP on the DMZ network but can't ping it, I think this might be a routing issue but I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated! Please see below for 'ifconfig eth1' and 'route -n':

```
Destination    Gateway      Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
0.0.0.0        172.20.20.1  0.0.0.0        UG     100     0    0    eth1
172.20.10.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    eth0
172.20.20.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    eth1

eth1

Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:ae:00:08
inet addr: 172.20.20.151  Bcasr:172.20.20.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr : fe80::250:56ff:feae:8/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTCAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets: 23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX Packets:22  errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txquwuwlwn:1000
RX bytes:2306 (2.3 KB) TX bytes:1794 (1.7KB)
```

Thanks, Charlotte.

Comment: Where are you pinging from? Or you can't ping it from the local machine?

Comment: I can ping 172.20.20.151 from the local machine, but not from another machine on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to my comment above...

You should let know to the other machines on the LAN **how to reach** the `172.20.20.0/24` subnet.

You said that the LAN address is assigned by DHCP. So I suppose this server is **not** your `default gateway` for the LAN.

First, you should reconfigure it as a static address (say `172.20.10.100`), then:

- Put a route for `172.20.20.0/24` via `172.20.10.100` (the static **LAN** IP) on the `default gateway` of your LAN.
- Enable `ip forwarding` on your server, by issueing the command:

  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

**Note**: to permanently enable `ip forwarding` edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and make sure it has the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.
On my ubuntu machine there's something like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```