# Share Connection Without Nat

Tags: connection-sharing

How to Share a connection on Ubuntu Server without NAT

eth0: 192.168.10.156
eth1: 192.168.5.1

I am creating a Cache Server with TPROXY (squid 3.1), but in my network will not use nat as to deliver IP publicos all machines. In all the tutorials that were always observe the configuration of Ubuntu Server always used nat. But need this model:

eth1 (192.168.5.1)> It receives the data and passes it to eth0 (192.168.10.156 Internet)

Squid does its processing and returns the data to the network!

This works with Nat, but do not want to use NAT because the Squid configuration is with TPROXY (Transparent> Ip Client that should appear on the Internet and not Squid "would NAT")

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing This is possible with the right routing tables and forwarding rules. Without NAT, as these are already private RFC1918 addresses. If you make sure both the current NAT device and the PC sharing know about the 192.168.5.0 network, then it's just a IPv4 routing question/answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk, Thanks for noticing that. I'll remove it.

Comment: Your question changed from a routing/networking question to a Squid HTTP proxy question. This is totally different. I think you'll need a bit more basic IPv4 knowledge here. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Very general answer

There's very little information given in the question, so I'm assuming the following:

- Your 192.168.10.0 network is already NATed.
- You have access on this NAT (router) device.
- It is capable of adding manual static routes.
- No firewalls running.
- Your networks are of size /24 (= subnet mask 255.255.255.0).

#### Summary

In the steps below it makes all devices aware of the different networks and the routes, all done by regular IPv4 networking and using the Linux routing table. It's needed to enable forwarding on the PC sharing, as it will prevent you from doing this by default (security reasons).

#### Detailed steps

Then follow these (general) steps:

1. On the current NAT (router), add a static route:

   `192.168.5.0`/24 via `192.168.10.156`. I don't know what device you have, so I can't provide instructions for doing this. Read the manual of it.

   In case this router is running Ubuntu already, just add the route like this:

   ```
   route add -net 192.168.5.0/24 gw 192.168.10.156
   ```
2. On the PC you want to share the `192.168.5.0`/24 network, make sure it will forward the traffic:

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

   More info in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/134460/88802).
3. On the client PC make the route to the `192.168.10.0`/24 network known by adding it to the route table:

   ```
   route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 gw 192.168.5.1
   ```

Comment: Ok,
In this Case:
Computer 192.168.5.2 (Connected on Eth1 of ubuntu) don't ping on 192.168.10.1, and (192.168.10.1) is a gateway on may MK whith internet connection. What Client don't ping on 192.168.10.1 ?

Comment: @TomJunqueira I've tried re-reading your comment several times, and I am confused as to what you're trying to tell/ask in it. Update your question with your attempts and results instead. This site is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site.

Comment: Post Edited for more details

Answer (score -1):

By principle, what you want to do is a NAT. The action of taking inside network requests to the internet and convert it to a single external IP, for requesting to you internet provider, is a NAT function.

I think what you want is not have to use iptables, and its not nice, due to security reasions. At least a masquerade you need to use.

on /etc/init.d/rc.local add the code:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

this may help you without too much codes.

Comment: OP doesn't want NAT.

Comment: Louis Matthijssen, take a better look on the answer. What he wants is NAT. He just don't know what is a NAT.